# How come the list.remove() function skips elements to delete from times to times?

Tags: python

I send a daily email to a large amount of addresses, to both internal (to my company) and external addresses.
I want to downsize a mailing list by using an internal distribution list.
In my initial list, there are 3 kind of addresses:

1. External addresses
2. Internal addresses also included on the distribution list
3. Internal addresses not included on the distribution list.

I start with the current list of addresses, split it on whether internal or external, then remove internal addresses that are already on the distribution list.
Finally, i regroup external addresses (1) and internal ones that are not on the distribution list (3), add the distribution list address, and write all to a file.

I've added an tests to try and isolate the addresses that get skipped. It's always the same few ones, but eyeballing the import file and also the variable explorer, i can't see any pattern that would differentiate those from other addresses.

```py
addresses = process('Z:\mailing_list.txt')
distribution_list = process('Z:\distribution_list.txt')
internal = []
external = []

# Splitting email addresses in two lists (internal and external people)
for address in addresses:
    if '@my_company' in address:
        internal.append(address)
    else:
        external.append(address)

# Remove internal addresses already in the distribution list
for address in internal:
    print('address in internal: ', address)
    if address in distribution_list:
        # in a handful of cases, address is found in distribution list
        print(address, ' is in the distribution_list')
        # ...hence it must be removed...
        internal.remove(address)
        # ... yet the test below shows 'True' (the majority of the addresses show 'False', as expected)
        print('Still in internal? ', address in internal)
```

I would expect that each email address that is correctly found in the distribution_list, to be removed accordingly.
Normal case:

```py
ice.cube@my_company.com  is in the distribution_list
Still in internal?  False
```

But a in a few occurences, either it is removed upon second pass (no idea why it does a second pass on the element)

```py
missy.elliott@my_company.com  is in the distribution_list
Still in internal?  True
address in internal:  missy.elliott@my_company.com

missy.elliott@my_company.com  is in the distribution_list
Still in internal?  False
```

...or the name is skipped entirely, and still appears in the final list written to doc, when it shouldn't.

Thanks for the help,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weird behavior removing elements from a list in a loop in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350202/weird-behavior-removing-elements-from-a-list-in-a-loop-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are *modifying `internal` while iterating over it*. This leads to bad things.

Example:

```
l = list(range(10))

for element in l:
    if element in [2, 7, 8]:
        l.remove(element)

print(l)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]  # 8 is still in here...?
```

What you should do instead is use a `list` comprehension:

```
new_internal = [address for address in internal if address not in distribution_list]
```

If you want to additionally print elements that are removed:

```
def also_print(element):
    print(element)
    return element

new_internal = [also_print(address) for address in internal if address not in distribution_list]
```

Comment: Thanks gmds, your solution is indeed far more pythonic. I'll pick it over mine.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any intersection between the different lists? [From the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), `list.remove()` only removes the **first** occurrence of the given element.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

Multiple occurences of addresses in the mailing list made the condition remain true despite removing one occurence.

I added a while loop to ensure i remove all occurences of an address before moving to the next one.

Thanks all,